# Identifying application uniquely and include a check in a file shared by more than one application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have two iPad applications and there is one common project used my both these applications. In order to implement a particular task for UI, I need to deal with a file in the Common project that is being shared. But,when I am working with this file which is there in that project shared by my both applications, I have to check what application is running and make  changes appropriately. In case first application is currently running, then I should execute a function and in case if second application is running, I should not execute this function. Is there any way to check which application is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary to do this at runtime?
You could use a preprocessor macro like so:

```
//Somewhere, e.g in a config file, that is not shared by your applications
#define PROJECT_A

//In your shared file.
#ifdef PROJECT_A
//Specific code goes here
#endif
```

Otherwise you could use the bundle identifier you can then compare it to the identifier of the app.

```
if ([[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"] isEqualToString:@"Your bundle identifier"]) {
    //Specific code goes here
}
```

Comment: I tried with the bundle identifier approach and it worked. Thank you!